# Nodemailer: ERR_CONNECTION_RESET with AngularJS and NodeJS with POST

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, email, nodemailer

Following is the post data I am trying to send to NodeJS from AngularJS using POST method:

```
$scope.doStuff = function(foo, bar) {
    $http({method: 'post', url: '/send', data: {foo: foo, bar: bar}}).
        success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log(data);
    });
};
```

And following is the how I am receiving data on the server end using NodeJS:

```
 router.post('/send',function(req,res){

    var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        service: 'Gmail',
        auth: {
            user: 'foobar@gmail.com',
            pass: 'foobar'
        }
    });
    var mailOptions = {
        from: 'Foo Bar ✔ <foobar@gmail.com>',
        to: req.body.foo, // list of receivers
        subject: "Hello FooBar", 
        text: 'Hello ' + req.body.foo,
        html: "<p>Hello FooBar, you rock!</p>"
    };
    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){
        if(error){
            console.log(error);
        }else{
            console.log('Message sent: ' + info.response);
        }
    });
});
```

I am just trying to send email using nodemailer and I've been able to send the email alright.
But I get a `POST http://localhost:3000/send net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET`  on the console once the request has been sent.
Sometimes I also get `POST http://localhost:3000/send net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE` on the console.

Could somebody help me understand that why do I get that on the console and how to resolve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't return a response from your route.

```
res.send(200)
```

Answer (score 1):

Previously when i was working with `nodemailer` module, i also had same issues. It may be possibly some server mis-configuration because the code worked fine on my local server. And on live, it shows `Error: connect ECONNREFUSED`. I've tried a lot to resolve this issue, but, unsuccessful. So at last i switched to other module i.e. [Mailer](https://www.npmjs.org/package/mailer) . 
It has worked fine for me, you can give it a try.

Comment: https://github.com/Marak/node_mailer has been depricated in favour of nodemailer.